# Keras/Tensorflow in RStudio not referencing Python in Miniconda Environment

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras

so I've been trying to use Keras with Miniconda on my machine for a few weeks now (in Rstudio) and I've still been unable to make significant progress.

Most recently, here are the steps I followed:

1. create an environment in Miniconda, using Python 3.6
2. Download R and RStudio (an older version, Version 3.6.0) into said environment and run them
3. Install Keras into the environment (after Rcpp, Devtools etc)
4. Attempt to install Tensorflow

But then I get the error message that my Python installation isn't found and the bindings aren't loaded.
I've put the environment on the PATH, as well as the location where Python is and some folders within the environment.

I followed the advice given in a comment in my last post, which helped me to create the environment, but now Python isn't loading in Miniconda and I'm so so frustrated that I haven't been able to make this work. Please help.

When I look for the Python version I get this:

`C:\Users\NK>python --version [1] Python 3.8.4rc1`

Here is the beginning of the code I'm running:

```
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)
library(reticulate)

use_python("C:\\Users\\NK\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps", required=T)
Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_MINICONDA_PATH = "C:/mini/envs/r_3.6.0.1")
mnist <- dataset_mnist()
```

and I get this error:

`Error: Installation of Python not found, Python bindings not loaded. Use reticulate::install_miniconda() if you'd like to install a Miniconda Python environment.` even though I'm doing this entirely in a Miniconda environment. I'm even opening RStudio straight from the Miniconda command prompt.

Some basic info: Dell XPS 15 running Windows 10, using RStudio

Side question: Is there an easier way to do all this? It's been *fatiguing.*

Comment: Does anyone have any tips or advice? All thoughts are appreciated, thank you :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work! Here were my steps for anyone who stumbles across this:

1. Reinstall Anaconda
2. Create Anaconda Environment with Python 2.7 and R
3. Install Keras and Tensorflow packages and dependencies one by one into the environment through Anaconda
4. Install RStudio in the environment through Anaconda
5. use `use_python("[env]", required=T)` and `Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_MINICONDA_PATH = "[env]")` in any scripts you run using Keras